# count in select query

Tags: php, mysql

I have the following query:

```
select exam_id,semester_id from marks where student_id=150  and semester_id<=1914;
```

Its output is:

```
exam_id     |    semester_id

   27               1913
   68               1913
   64               1914
```

I want to find out the count of similar `semester_id`.

when I try `mysql_num_rows` it shows 3.

But I want output like this

```
 semester_id 1913---------->count 2
 semester_id 1914---------->count 1
```

Comment: All the following suggestions to use *count* while *group*ing the result-set are correct :) im voting for @Siva since most of the other repliers already have a good reputation ;)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You just use `GROUP BY`:

```
SELECT semester_id, COUNT(*) as count
 FROM marks  
 WHERE student_id=150 
  AND semester_id<=1914
 GROUP BY semester_id;
```

Answer (score 3):

try this

```
select semester_id,count(*) as cnt 
from marks 
where student_id=150 and semester_id<=1914 
group by semester_id;
```

Answer (score 3):

Use `Count()` aggregate function you can achieve this.

```
 SELECT semester_id, COUNT(exam_id)  FROM marks  
 WHERE student_id=150  AND semester_id<=1914
 GROUP BY semester_id;
```

Comment: no its also showing 1913--->count 1 1914->count 1@Shailesh Katarmal

Answer (score 1):

```
Select semester_id, count(exam_id)
From marks
Group By semester_id;
```

if you feel the need, use:

```
count(distinct exam_id)
```

Comment: thanks for giving replies but each query shows only same output i.e both count only 1

Answer (score 1):

Use count()

```
SELECT semester_id, COUNT(*) as count
FROM marks  
WHERE student_id=150 
AND semester_id<=1914
GROUP BY semester_id;
```